# Getting segmentation faults on QFile::setFileName

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, ros

For a logging feature using ROS rqt+Qt4 I am trying to write to multiple files in a hardcoded folder hierarchy.

I have a parent class inheriting from QtWidget holding multiple QFile* members. I then assign them storage with *filehandle = new QFile(this).

Writing to the files works fine, but if I try to even set the Filename on the filehandles for reading the logfiles, I get an immediate Segmentation fault. However, not for all of the files I can see no consistent pattern in what file paths are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Some code would help.

From what I can see, the result of the new is a *QFile that should be assigned to another *QFile

```
QFile * filehandle;

*filehandle = new QFile(this)     //is wrong

filehandle = new QFile(this)      //is right
```

Remember that segmentation faults come from access to memory that has not been correctly reserved or that have been fred early with a delete statement.

If you stuck to much in a segmentation fault problem a quick way to know where is the problem is to run your program with a debugger (gdb). If you use QT Creator the process is really easy.

Comment: QtCreator + RQT not so easy..i finally gave up and changed it to store the handles on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error i was declaring QFile as a private variable inside my class.

```
QFile  archivo_pattern_bin;
```

then using it to open an hex file in the indicated absolute path

```
archivo_pattern_bin.setFileName(pattern_file_path);
archivo_pattern_bin.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
archivo_pattern_bin.flush();
```

this returned the windows segmentation error when debugging exactly at setFileName()

But now im just declaring a pointer

```
QFile * archivo_pattern_bin;
```

and creating the Qfile object dynamically

```
archivo_pattern_bin = new QFile(this);
archivo_pattern_bin->setFileName(pattern_file_path);
archivo_pattern_bin->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
archivo_pattern_bin->flush();
```

**Also i was writting an array outside its defined size thus corrupting everything.......**

and everything is alright now :D
thanks pablo